# User chooses file directory to backup a database C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have successfully coded a button to backup a database to a certain directory, but I have no clue on how I can allow the user to select their own backup directory.

**.aspx**

```xaml
<label>Backup File Name:</label>
&nbsp;<asp:textbox type="text" id="txtb" runat="server" cssclass="form-control" width="30%" />

<label>File Directory:</label>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button111_Click" Text="backup" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
```

**.cs**

```
protected void Button111_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ToString());

    string backupDIR = "C:\\backup";
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(backupDIR))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(backupDIR);
    }
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(
            "backup database iporma to disk= '" + backupDIR + "\\"+txtb.Text+"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy_HHss") + ".bak'", con);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblError.Text = "Completed backup file  located C:\\backup";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Error" + ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of having it hardcoded, add a text box, and let them fill it with the backup directory, and use it.

Comment: And please, for the 1.000th time: **Don't concat your strings for sql queries! Use [prepared statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx), you are vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"select their own backup directory"*?

Comment: Sorry I will fix my sql statements. What I mean when I said they will choose their backup directory like when you want to download a file you choose a folder that you want the file you wish to download and select it and when you press the "ok" button the downloaded file goes to the folder that you have selected, I would like to know how to "choose" the folder

Comment: @clint Well, you can't have an sql-server backup a databse to the users PC directly, you would have to make that a 2-step process. Secondly, browsers don't let you choose directories, only single files for security reasons.